# Group is linked to an invisible point i can't delete

Tags: groups

i'm having this problem for a couple of days and i have no idea how to solve it.

I have my meshed character (hot dog), i've created my rig and now i'd like to start my skinning.  When i try to group (CTRL-P), my character links to a remote point and i can't start skinning.

You can find the .blend file here:      http://dropcanvas.com/ief1p

Any idea would be welcome...  thanks for your help

Comment: `Ctrl`+`P` Doesn't group objects, it parents them with a child-parent relationship, `Ctrl`+`G` is used to group objects. The "remote point" is probably the mesh center wich is not centered with the geometry

Answer (score 1):

You have 2-3 empty objects, objects which do not contain any vertices.

[image: outliner highlighting problem objects]

Out of those HotyDog_CH contains a shoe object which contains a HyperNURBS object which contains Cube1 which in turn contains the actual mesh data of your character:

[image: outliner highlighting mesh location]

Now first of all, maintain a clean workspace, delete the emptys, and generally check the outliner tab and check that there are no unwanted objects, also naming your objects will make your life easier.

Second is that you have some unapplied scales which will give you lots of headaches, so before deleting those empty containers or parenting to the armature apply your scale with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

After that you should be able to properly parent your mesh to your armature and begin skinning. Be sure to first select your mesh, then your armature and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Off topic:

• check your hand rigging, as it has some faulty and missing connections.

• you have unmerged vertice data, this will cause shading artifacts, enter edit mode and remove doubles  <kbd>W</kbd>  -> Remove Doubles.